# Simple ASP.NET/C# Problem - Events

Tags: c#, events

I have a class that inherits from the LinkButton ASP.NET control to include an int "Value" property for remembering a database ID when creating LinkButtons dynamically. This is so I can load some database driven content based on that ID on postback.

My question is: Is there a simple way to achieve this in C#? I have had a look around the internet and got a lot of info on delegates & custom event handling but it seems overly complex for what I need to do. Should I be reading up on delegates, generics & events or can I just override the LinkButtons Click event to capture the ID and query the DB?

*EDIT*

I'm creating my controls dynamically so I'm not sure how to link up an event to the click event of the dynamically added control. I take the points below about the CommandArgument property but does anyone have an example of using CommandArgument with a dynamically created control?

```
var lnkbtnTitle = new LinkButton();

            lnkbtnTitle.CssClass = "ABC";
            lnkbtnTitle.ToolTip = Description;
            lnkbtnTitle.Text = Name + ' ' + Version;
            lnkbtnTitle.CommandArgument = ID.ToString();
            pnlHelpGuidesView.Controls.Add(lnkbtnTitle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved my own problem here and it turns out to be a rookie problem I have encountered before! I figured it was worth any potential embarrassment to post the resolution here for anyone else's benefit...

**WHEN YOU CREATE DYNAMIC CONTROLS YOU MUST RECREATE THEM ON POSTBACK**

This always seemed counter-intuitive to me but I had a if(!IsPostBack) directive on my control creation code, which meant that any solutions I tried the events did not fire. This was because the control no longer existed because I did not recreate it on postback.

In answer to my own question and taking on-board the points mentioned here, the following code works...

```
private void DrawHelpGuide(int ID, int Type, string Name, string Description, string Version, string URL)
    {
            var lnkbtnTitle = new LinkButton();

            lnkbtnTitle.CssClass = "HelpGuideTitle";
            lnkbtnTitle.ToolTip = Description;
            lnkbtnTitle.Text = Name + ' ' + Version;
            lnkbtnTitle.CommandArgument = ID.ToString();
            lnkbtnTitle.Click += new EventHandler(lnkbtnTitle_Click);
            pnlHelpGuidesView.Controls.Add(lnkbtnTitle);
        }

    void lnkbtnTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ClickedButton = (LinkButton)sender;
        var id = int.Parse(ClickedButton.CommandArgument);
    }
```

I now also realise that the various versions I wrote previously, while more complex, would also have worked! In my specific case the CommandArgument method is perfectly adequate but I'm very pleased I now "get" the concept of delegates & events a lot more than I did previously :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need inherit from the linkButton to just attach an "ID" property, linkbutton has a property called "CommandArgument" which you can utilize to store this ID, and sent it on Postback.

Answer (score 1):

The LinkButton control already has a [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx) property for this purpose. All you need to do is handle the Click or Command events, cast the CommandArgument to int, and you've captured the ID.